# Error Deploying Flask Web Scraping App on Vercel

Tags: python, pandas, flask, beautifulsoup, vercel

I've been working on my first web scraping app using Flask, and it runs smoothly on my laptop. However, I'm facing an issue when trying to deploy it on Vercel. The error message says, "Function Runtimes must have a valid version, for example `now-php@1.0.0`."

Here's the structure of my app:

```
table-extractor-app/
├── app.py
├── static/
│   ├── images/
│   │   └── table.png
│   ├── styles.css
│   └── script.js
└── templates/
    └── frontend/
        └── index.html        
├── requirements.txt
├── vercel.json
```

And this is my `vercel.json`:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "app.py": {
      "runtime": "python3.10.2"
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/extract_table",
      "methods": ["POST"],
      "dest": "/app.py"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/app.py"
    }
  ],
  "version": 2
}
```

I suspect the issue is in my `vercel.json` file. Can someone help me identify the problem and suggest a fix? Thanks a bunch!                                                                      https://github.com/tanmay-kalbande/table-extractor-app

Tried deploying Flask app on Vercel, expected smooth execution, but faced a "Function Runtimes must have a valid version" error in `vercel.json`.

Answer (score 0):

you should try setting node.js on the project settings page. You don’t need to specify the node.js version here, so the problem is in function.config as per my understanding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).